# Share text to Facebook Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, share

I'm trying to share some text on Facebook via my iOS application.
I've managed to get it working in a Swift written application like this:

```
@IBAction func shareAction(sender: AnyObject) {

if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
    var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    facebookSheet.setInitialText("Preadded text")
    self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

} else {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

} }
```

However, my code is written in Objective-C. My question is, is there a similar way of writing this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing the [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/index.html)

```
-(void)fbButton {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        fbSLComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fbSLComposeViewController addImage:someImage];
        [fbSLComposeViewController setInitialText:@"Some Text"];
        [self presentViewController:fbSLComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        fbSLComposeViewController.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            switch(result) {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"facebook: CANCELLED");
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    NSLog(@"facebook: SHARED");
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *fbError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Unavailable" message:@"Sorry, we're unable to find a Facebook account on your device.\nPlease setup an account in your devices settings and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [fbError show];
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't add the text "Some Text" to the post. Any idea on why it won't do it?

Comment: @MrRiksson Apparently this is a bug in iOS 8.3. This was working prior to the latest iOS update. Just checked my applications that have this implemented and it is not working anymore. I have submitted a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Also, `SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled` is not being called anymore if you cancel the post.

Comment: Pretty interesting. However I assume that Apple will have a fix for this soon. Any who, thanks for the answer! Truly appreciated

Comment: You are aware that the user have to write every single character of the message according to the Facebook Platform Policy?

Comment: I'm assuming this is pretty new then? I mean people used to share game scores etc to Facebook before.

Comment: @wizkid this may be true when implementing Facebook's SDK but when using the Social Framework like I mentioned this is absolutely possible. I've used it since it first became available. Please read the Apple Docs I've linked in my answer. The setInitialText specifically.

Comment: You are allowed to set the text if the user wrote it. Otherwise not

Comment: I assume you have a Facebook app ID? So you accepted that you will follow the Facebook platform policy. Have you read it?

Comment: A Facebook app ID is not required to use Facebook sharing via the Social Framework. I beg you to read the docs @WizKid

Comment: I would still suggest that you don't break Facebook Platform Policy.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];        
    }
}
```

### [Reference](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/)

Comment: It works if I add a URL to share. However it doesn't post the text I've set

Comment: @MrRiksson : [you should take a look at this issues](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=slcomposeviewcontroller%20not%20working%20in%20ios%208.3)